# How to do a basic javascript loop / accessing array data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have been searching A LOT to find a simple way to loop through an array (I haven't used javascript much) and I just can't seem to make sense of the examples I've seen.

I also want to retrieve data from an array...

The following example I can understand:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

But it's just not useful for the use case I want it for.

Say I have an array that looks like this:

```
array1 = [{'key':1, 'values':["one", "1"]}, {'key':2, 'values':["two", "2"]}]
```

Question 1: How can I access the first object in that array, i.e. where the 'key' = 1?

Question 2: How can I then loop through the "values" from this object?

e.g. In Python I would do something like:

```
get_first_object = array1[0]

for value in array1['values']:
    print value
```

How can I do this kind of coding in javascript?

**Edit**
I didn't mention this properly
My "array1" is coming from a Python view and so the output of this is different to a standard JS array (see output of console.log below):

```
["[{'key': 1, 'values': ["one", "1"]}, {'key': 2, 'values':["two", "2"]}]"]
```

so when I do `var object = array1[0]` I get the following output:

```
[{'key': 1, 'values': ["one", "1"]}, {'key': 2, 'values': ["two", "2"]}]
```

It doesn't seem to be getting the first object but rather seeing the whole thing as one object.

**Also**

I require to get this dynamically - so I can't actually hard code "array1[0]" or "array1[1]" - How can I do this?

**How I am defining the array**

```
var array1 = ["{{ my_array_1|safe }}"];
```

**Edit 2**

The way I wish to get the object from the array is like so:
var selected_id = 1;

```
var selected_object = array[key=selected_id];
```

Comment: There are different kind of loops in javascript the for value in object works with the prototypal chain to get the values of each key of the object. check a few more posibilities on how to iterate through the array here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that your array is this:

```
var array = [{'key': 1, 'values': ["one", "1"]}, {'key': 2, 'values': ["two", "2"]}];
```

This is an array which contains javascript objects, each with 2 properties, `'key'`, whose corresponding value is an integer and `'values'` whose corresponding value is an array of data. If I understand this correctly, you want, given an integer `input_id`, to access the aforementioned array of data.

```
function access_data (id) {

    for(let obj of array){
        if(obj['key'] == id){
            return obj['values'];
        }
    }
}
```

If you are familiar with python you probably recognize the `for .... of` syntax, since it's basically the same as python's `for .... in`. The above code assumes that your array is a `global` variable called `array`. Calling the function with an integer argument loops through every object your array contains, checks if its `'key'` property matches the given `id`, and if it does, the corresponding array of data is returned.

More details on `for ... of` loops [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Comment: Hi thanks for this - but could you please look at my edit - I didn't detail as much as I should have in original post

Comment: @richard_m_simms In your second edit you mention that you want to retrieve data from the array like so `var selected_object = array[key=selected_id];` . Is `selected_id` an integer? Could you provide an example of an input and expected output?

Comment: I am expecting to get a variable (passed in from a form input) e.g. "selected_id" and then get the key with selected id from the array using the variable -  is this possible.

Comment: @richard_m_simms So if i were to fill this form, and give the `selected_id` a value of 1, would you expect the output to be `["one", "1"]` ? Am i getting this? If i am wrong please tell me what the output should be

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i would expect, and then I plan on looping around the values, i.e. "one" and "1" and doing stuff with them.

Comment: Hi, thanks your update is great - just one final thing then I think this answer will be perfect - inside the loop you are performing, inside the if statement, i need to then loop through each value - i've just tried this: for (val in obj['values']){ - but getting none returned

Comment: ahh I forgot the let and of. I've accepted your answer but it wont let me upvote it. thanks alot

Comment: @richard_m_simms don't worry, glad i could help. Yes watch out because the syntax is different. The logic is still the same though.

Answer (score 0):

You can hardcode it: `array1[0].key // 1`
Use `forEach` to loop over:

```
const array1 = [{'key':1, 'values':["one", "1"]}, {'key':2, 'values':["two", "2"]}]

array1.forEach(arrItem => console.log(arrItem))
```

Or `map` over it if you intend to change datas as @str said below:

```
const array1 = [{'key':1, 'values':["one", "1"]}, {'key':2, 'values':["two", "2"]}]

array1.map(arrayItem => console.log(arrayItem);
```

On `map`vs `forEach`:
https://codeburst.io/javascript-map-vs-foreach-f38111822c0f

Comment: Don't use `map` but `forEach` to iterate over an array. `map` is used to *change* the array.

Answer (score 0):

This self explanatory code should rectify your doubts

```js
var array1 = [{'key':1, 'values':["one", "1"]}, {'key':2, 'values':["two", "2"]}];

// First Object
var firstObject = array1[0];
console.log("First object", firstObject);

// Accessing key property of first object
var keyOfFirstObj = firstObject.key;
console.log("Key", keyOfFirstObj);

// Iterating through all the values of first object
Object.values(firstObject).forEach(
  el => console.log("Value -- ", el)
)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this - but could you please look at my edit - I didn't detail as much as I should have in original post

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, the basic `for` loop and the `for..of` loop

#### for

```
for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  console.log(array1[i])
}
```

#### for..of

```
for (const val of array1) {
  console.log(val)
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

if you want to select an object that has a key property of "1", you could loop through the array using the methods above, returung when that condition is true, or you could use Array#filter

```
const filtered = array1.filter(item => item['key'] === 1)  //=> returns a new array
const myObj = filtered[0]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this - but could you please look at my edit - I didn't detail as much as I should have in original post

Answer (score 0):

If you want a similar syntax to Python, you Coups use the for...in loop:

```
let get_first_object = array1[0];

for (let index in array1['values']){
    console.log(array1['values'][index]);
    }
```

Edit:
As for your edit, you need 2 loops

```
let objectArray= array1[0];

if(objectArray){
    for(let outerIndex in objectArray){
       for(let innerIndex in objectArray[outerIndex]['values']){
          console.log(objectArray[outerIndex]['values'][innerIndex]; 
       }
    }
}
```

Edit:

```
let objectArray= array1[0];

if(objectArray){
    let valuesObject=objectArray.filter(f=>f.key===selectedId);
       for(let innerIndex in valuesObject['values']){
          console.log(valuesObject ['values'][innerIndex]; 
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this - but could you please look at my edit - I didn't detail as much as I should have in original post

Comment: @richard_m_simms I did.

Comment: Did my answer target your needs?

Comment: Hi - thanks, it almost does. my problem is the output of "objectArray" is returning the entire array. also I want to be able to get the particular object from the array using a variable, i.e. array1[key=selected_id]

Comment: And why don‘t you do that?

Comment: @richard_m_simms I hope this helps you.